# removing an element from a list in lisp

Tags: list, lisp

I'm working on an assignment for a computer science class and I've run into a snag. I know that the community is against giving out explicit answers to homework projects, and that isn't really what I am here for; I'm looking to be put on the right track or thought process. I'll try to give as much information as possible in order to give you an idea of what I am dealing with and how I am blocked.

First off, this is a very quick "introduction" to the language of LISP. The course is taking us through several different types of languages to give us some insight into different aspects of programming as well as the history of their development. As such, the project rules are as follows:

- Cannot use any looping functions; instead, must use recursion
- Can only use the following inherent functions **setq**, **cons**, **append**, **list**, **equal**, **defun**, **car**, **cdr**, and **cond**
- Can create "helping functions" that can be used to create an extra step in a function's conditions (sort of like a nested cond)

The part I am having trouble with is that I am supposed to create a function that takes a list as a parameter, scans that list for duplicates, and removes the duplicates, returning the list back. So if I passed a list of '(a b c b a d e a) it would return (a b c d e).

So far, I thought it best to create a function called **list_member** that compares an element to a list and returns T if the element is in the list or nil if it is not in the list.

```
(defun list_member (x L)
  (cond ((null L) nil)             ;if list L is empty, return NIL
    ((equal x (car L)) T)          ;if element x is in L, return T
    (T (list_member x (cdr L)))))  ;else, recursively check remainder of L
```

And I want to use it in the function, rem_dup, which I have started filling out below:

```
(defun rem_dup (L)
   (cond ((null L) nil)                     ;if list L is empty, return NIL to user
     (( list_member (car L) cdr L )) (...)  ;part I am having trouble with
     (T (rem_dup (cdr L)))))                ;else, check rest of list recursively
```

My issue is that I cannot seem to figure out, with the functions available, how to put together the list with the duplicates removed. Essentially I don't know where to start with what to do when list_member returns true. The only function that keeps a list format is APPEND because I am dealing with single elements (in this case even a nested list is considered an element). All of the list concatenating functions I can use (APPEND, CONS, LIST) are non-destructive.

I've come up with a lot of solutions but the list that is returned is not even close to what I want. I think listing them here would probably create confusion. I've come to a wall with asking myself the right questions, so I thought I'd put it to everyone to see if they can come up with a question to ask that I haven't thought of yet.

I appreciate your insights.

Comment: Can you create a copy of the list, or does it have to be the list itself, trimmed?

Comment: Please invest a few minutes to learn [how to format Lisp code](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the formatting link! Was basing my indentation off what the professor had shown us to do...maybe I'll send him the same link.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, your professor definitely shouldn't be teaching this indentation style to his students.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your cases backwards. If the first element is in the rest of the list, it's a duplicate, so you want to omit it. Otherwise, you want to return a list containing the first element consed onto the front of `rem_dup` of the rest.

```
(defun rem_dup (L)
   (cond ((null L) nil)                         ; if list L is empty, return NIL to user
         ((list_member (car L) (cdr L )) (rem_dup (cdr L))) ; Skip duplicate element
         (T (cons (car L) (rem_dup (cdr L)))))) ; else include it, and check rest of list recursively
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. I have a couple more functions involving similar processes in the project. This should help with figuring them out!